# Objective C: Auto Layout with existing Custom View changing bounds width and height to 0,0

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

OK.  I'm just learning about CALayers, because I've inherited someone else's code.  There is a view which takes up the entire background (minus the toolbar) and then a subview which takes up a small rectangle near the bottom of the view.  I'm trying to use Auto Layout. It is the background view I am having trouble with.  I've tried pinning the width and height and several other things I know to get the height and width to stay the size of the view (320 x 505).  I'm not sure if the layers are messing me up or if it's the other view.  Anyway here is the code in question.  With Auto Layout turned off the width and height are correct.  With Auto Layout turned on the width and height become negative numbers and get set to zero.  Any ideas on how to fix this?

```
    UIView *view = [self videoPreviewView];        
    CGRect bounds = [[self videoPreviewView] bounds];  //bounds gets set here
                                                       //values are same as below

    [self setCaptureManager:captureManager];

    AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *captureVideoPreviewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:[captureManager session]];

    CALayer *viewLayer = [view layer];
    [viewLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];

   [captureVideoPreviewLayer setFrame:bounds];  //Use Autolayout off:  x=0, y=0, width=320, height=504
                                                //Use Autolayout on:   x=0, y=0, width=0, height=0
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With autolayout on, the subviews constraints are not yet calculated in viewDidLoad, resulting in frame equals to CGRectZero. You should move your frame setting code into viewDidLayoutSubviews method instead.

From the class reference explaining viewDidLayoutSubviews:

> Notifies the view controller that its view just laid out its subviews.

Which is precisely after the autolayout has done its job calculating the constraints and putting the subviews in place.

Comment: I was struggling with the behavior of an AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer in iOS 8 and this was the answer. Needed to delay my setting of the layer frame until viewDidLayoutSubviews, instead of viewDidLoad.